# Tensorflow - How do I make the model I generate in Tensorflow-Python usable in Tensorflow-Android with TensorFlowInferenceInterface?

Tags: android, python, opencv, tensorflow

As it is right now, I have a CNN model I want to use in Android devices but generated in Python. In Python I use the `tf.Estimator()` to generate the model, like this:

```
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="F:/python_machine_learning_codes/tmp/lfw_adam_3")
```

The beginning part of the `cnn_model_fn` looks like this:

```
x = features["x"]  
#x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64*64*3], name="input")  
input_layer = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 64, 64, 3])
```

The CNN model initiation code in Python looks like this:

```
def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data

  train_pickles = Path("F:/python_machine_learning_codes/train_pickle.pkl")
  if train_pickles.is_file():
      with open("F:/python_machine_learning_codes/train_pickle.pkl", 'rb') as train_pkl:
          train_data, train_labels = pickle.load(train_pkl)
  else:
      train_data, train_labels = filenames(True)
      with open("F:/python_machine_learning_codes/train_pickle.pkl", 'wb') as train_pkl:
          pickle.dump([train_data, train_labels], train_pkl)

  # Create the Estimator
  mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="F:/python_machine_learning_codes/tmp/lfw_adam_3")

  # Set up logging for predictions
  # Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=100)

  # Train the model
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_data},
      y=train_labels,
      batch_size=64,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)
  mnist_classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=100,
      hooks=[logging_hook])

  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_pickles = Path("F:/python_machine_learning_codes/eval_pickle.pkl")
  if eval_pickles.is_file():
      with open("F:/python_machine_learning_codes/eval_pickle.pkl", 'rb') as eval_pkl:
          eval_data, eval_labels = pickle.load(eval_pkl)
  else:
      eval_data, eval_labels = filenames(False)
      with open("F:/python_machine_learning_codes/eval_pickle.pkl", 'wb') as eval_pkl:
          pickle.dump([eval_data, eval_labels], eval_pkl)

  eval_logs = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  eval_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=eval_logs, every_n_iter=100)
  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": eval_data},
      y=eval_labels,
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
  eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, hooks=[eval_hook])
  print(eval_results)
```

NOTE: `filenames(bool)` is just a function to fetch the image data from an acquired dataset (Adience 3D) and preprocess it by cropping the face area

However, when I tested the model in Android using both the `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` from the JCenter TensorFlow AAR and OpenCV's `dnn_modern` module (with `Dnn.readModelFromTensorflow()`), both don't recognize the node `enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queue` with the op `RandomShuffleQueueV2` (I have some reason to believe it's the input node, but I'm not completely sure because, from the name, I think it's used to shuffle the `features["x"]` array which is the real input).

The only thing I can think of is somehow replacing the `x` input above with a straight up `tf.Placeholder()`, or not use the `tf.Estimator()` in the first place and straight up run it in a `tf.Session()`. Or maybe build TensorFlow myself with `RandomShuffleQueueV2` or that `__ANDROID_FULL_TYPE__` flag.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to make a model usable in both Python and Android's `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` other than the ones I mentioned above?

EDIT:

The following is the list of the nodes I got from looking at the frozen model in a `tf.GraphDef()` just now:

```
['enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queue => RandomShuffleQueueV2',
 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany/n => Const',
 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany => QueueDequeueManyV2',
 'Reshape/shape => Const',
 'Reshape => Reshape',
 'conv2d/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d/kernel/read => Identity',
 'conv2d/bias => Const',
 'conv2d/bias/read => Identity',
 'conv2d/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d/Relu => Relu',
 'conv2d_1/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_1/kernel/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_1/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_1/bias/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_2/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_2/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_2/Relu => Relu',
 'max_pooling2d/MaxPool => MaxPool',
 'conv2d_2/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_2/kernel/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_2/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_2/bias/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_3/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_3/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_3/Relu => Relu',
 'conv2d_3/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_3/kernel/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_3/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_3/bias/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_4/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_4/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_4/Relu => Relu',
 'max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool => MaxPool',
 'conv2d_4/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_4/kernel/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_4/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_4/bias/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_5/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_5/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_5/Relu => Relu',
 'conv2d_5/kernel => Const',
 'conv2d_5/kernel/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_5/bias => Const',
 'conv2d_5/bias/read => Identity',
 'conv2d_6/convolution => Conv2D',
 'conv2d_6/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'conv2d_6/Relu => Relu',
 'max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool => MaxPool',
 'Reshape_1/shape => Const',
 'Reshape_1 => Reshape',
 'dense/kernel => Const',
 'dense/kernel/read => Identity',
 'dense/bias => Const',
 'dense/bias/read => Identity',
 'dense/MatMul => MatMul',
 'dense/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'dense/Relu => Relu',
 'dropout/dropout/keep_prob => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/Shape => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/min => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/max => Const',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform => RandomUniform',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/sub => Sub',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform/mul => Mul',
 'dropout/dropout/random_uniform => Add',
 'dropout/dropout/add => Add',
 'dropout/dropout/Floor => Floor',
 'dropout/dropout/div => RealDiv',
 'dropout/dropout/mul => Mul',
 'dense_1/kernel => Const',
 'dense_1/kernel/read => Identity',
 'dense_1/bias => Const',
 'dense_1/bias/read => Identity',
 'dense_2/MatMul => MatMul',
 'dense_2/BiasAdd => BiasAdd',
 'softmax_tensor => Softmax']
```

I think I just found the real input node, the one named `Reshape/shape` with the op `Const`. So, how do I trim out the three nodes before it? Because I think they're used for training.

Comment: Have you tried to freeze your graph?

Comment: Already did, several times. I've just added the list of nodes I got from looking at the latest one in `tf.GraphDef()`

Comment: Do you have trained_graph.pb file and train_labels.txt

Comment: If by `trained_graph.pb` you mean the frozen graph, yes. Though I don't have `train_labels.txt` and don't know whether it's user-made or generated.

Comment: To use your trained graph in Android you need trained_graph.pb and respective classes (user-generated) in train_labels.txt file. Once you have that ping me I'll guide you.

Comment: Do I have to make the train_labels.txt file by hand by choosing the nodes I want to remove?